# Обращение к свойству объекта из другого qml файла? Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Как изменить свойство у объекта в другом файле QML ?

Answer (score 1):

Для изменения свойста объекта описанного в сторонем файле QML необходимо объявить property и присвоить ее значение необходимому свойству.

На примере:

файл ItemRect.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Item {
    height: 100
    width: 100

    property string myString

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "black"
    }

    Text {
        id: myText

        anchors.centerIn: parent

        text: myString
        font.pixelSize: 18
        color: "white"
    }
}
```

объявляем property string myString и присваиваем значение свойству text: объекта id: myText

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: main

    height: 300
    width: 300

    visible: true

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        spacing: 3

        ItemRect {
            id: myItem

            myString: "DEFAULT"
        }

        Button {
            id: btn

            text: "Change"

            onClicked: {
                myItem.myString = "Pasted Text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

при нажатии на кнопку в слоте onClicked: изменяем свойство у объекта id: myItem, описанного в ItemRect.qml